# CakePHP - Auth - $current_user - no ID, first_name, last_name etc

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

When I log in with:

```
$this->Auth->login($this->request->data)
```

And now, when I say:

```
$this->set('current_user', $this->Auth->user());
```

In my $current_user is **only** username and password. No ID, first_name, last_name etc. like in my database. Why? I need that data!

I tried $this->Auth->login() - without $this->request->data but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to send the request data to the login function, it will return a user based on the current post data if there is a match.

Here is my login function from my UserController.php

```
public function login() {
    if($this->Auth->user()) {
        $this->redirect('/');
    }

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password.'));
        }
    }
}
```

To lookup my user's fields in the view I set this up in AppController.php as such:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->set('user', $this->Auth->user());
    }

}
```

Then the `$user` is available in all of your views.

```
index.ctp

if($user) {
    echo var_dump($user);
}

array
  'id' => string '15' (length=2)
  'created' => string '2012-06-29 21:50:44' (length=19)
  'modified' => string '2012-06-29 21:50:44' (length=19)
  'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'username' => string 'user' (length=4)
  'email' => string 'email@email.com' (length=15)

echo $user['id']; -> 15
echo $user['email']; -> email@email.com
```

Comment: Brilliant answer. I must start posting examples. +1

Answer (score 0):

There was a change to the way the `Auth::login()` method works in 2.0. You now do not need to pass post data to the login method it will automatically fetch the data from the request object.

See the red box here for more information: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in